# Processes runing in all nodes but datanodes not connected to the namenode

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have a 4 nodes cluster 1 master and 3 slaves on CentOs ,and HADOOP 2.5.0 .

All of configs and ssh also is good :).

But when I run `start-dfs.sh` in master `namenod` and in slaves `datanode` jobs are running but in `web GUI` or `hadoop dfsadmin -report` No nodes not running :( .

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
192.168.1.201 master1  master1.foo.com
192.168.1.200 slave3 slave3.foo.com
192.168.1.203 slave1 slave1.foo.com
192.168.1.204 slave2 slave2.foo.com 
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

In all of hosts.

Comment: Can you check datanode logs,if any error

Answer (score 0):

get into

/home/hduser/hadoop/sbin/

then input  ***start-all.sh***

after that input ***jps***

this time ,  can u see your datanode is running ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: there is two ways to solve the problem that datanode can not run..1.<1>first,excute"stop-all.sh"<2>delete  "datanode"Folder in ../hadoop/hdfs<3>excute "hadoop namenode -format"<4>excute"start-all.sh" to see whether it can run .     2.<1>first,excute"stop-all.sh" <2>excute"chown -R ../hadoop/hdfs/datanode".<3>excute"start-all.sh" to see whether it can run .